# BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using ruby-build 20210405-4-gf948cdc)

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I'm trying to install ruby 2.6.5 via rbenv on unbutu on windows 10 but I have an error I don't understand how to solve it,

I tried a lot of solutions that I found on stackoverflow but I can't solve the problem.
it blocks when choosing the ruby version to install

the error :

> BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using ruby-build 20210405-4-gf948cdc)

I am following this tuto to try to install :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-18-04

[the errors img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F1rK.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your error is `error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH`

Run `sudo apt-get install build-essential` to install the C compiler.

you can see that its included in `Step 1 – Install rbenv and Dependencies` of the tutorial your following alongside other libraries `rbenv` needs

```sh
sudo apt install autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm5 libgdbm-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

1. $ `sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev`
2. $ `curl -fsSL https://gist.github.com/FiveYellowMice/c50490693d47577cfe7e6ac9fc3bf6cf.txt | rbenv install --patch 1.9.3-p551`

you can use any `version` instead of  `patch 1.9.3-p551`

3. $    `rbenv global 1.9.3-p551`
4. $ `ruby -v`

output:

```
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]
```